# Paging output from Go

Tags: go, stdout, pager

I'm trying print to stdout from golang using `$PAGER` or manually invoking `more` or `less` to allow the user to easily scroll through a lot of options. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The question is very unclear.  If you print to stdout and the user manually invokes a pager, then ... you've achieved what you want.

Comment: I think the question explains perfectly what I want. What I'm trying to achieve is to pipe the stdout of my go program to the call to $PAGER

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [os/exec](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package to start a process that runs `less` (or whatever is in `$PAGER`) and then pipe a string to its standard input. The following worked for me:

```
func main() {
    // Could read $PAGER rather than hardcoding the path.
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/less")

    // Feed it with the string you want to display.
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("The text you want to show.")

    // This is crucial - otherwise it will write to a null device.
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

    // Fork off a process and wait for it to terminate.
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Years ago (Oct 2012 according to `ls`) I [made a package to do something like this](https://gist.github.com/dchapes/1d0c538ce07902b76c75). I vaguely recall there was some problem/issue with actually using it however (e.g. I tried adding it to `godoc` to make it like `hg man` with the pager extension enabled, but I ended up back with just piping through a pager on the command line instead).

Comment: You can do [`w, err := cmd.StdinPipe()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#cmd.StdinPipe) to let arbitrary code write to the process through `w`.

Comment: You're right you could: `pager := os.ExpandEnv("$PAGER")`

Answer (score 3):

I assume you already have output being printed from your program to stdout that you want to have captured and sent to your pager, you don't want to
rewrite the I/O to use another input stream like the other responses require.

You can create an os.Pipe which works the same as running a command with "|less" by attaching one side to your pager and the other side to stdout like this:

```
// Create a pipe for a pager to use
r, w, err := os.Pipe()
if err != nil {
    panic("You probably want to fail more gracefully than this")
}

// Capture STDOUT for the Pager. Keep the old
// value so we can restore it later.
stdout := os.Stdout
os.Stdout = w

// Create the pager process to execute and attach
// the appropriate I/O streams.
pager := exec.Command("less")
pager.Stdin = r
pager.Stdout = stdout // the pager uses the original stdout, not the pipe
pager.Stderr = os.Stderr

// Defer a function that closes the pipe and invokes
// the pager, then restores os.Stdout after this function
// returns and we've finished capturing output.
//
// Note that it's very important that the pipe is closed,
// so that EOF is sent to the pager, otherwise weird things 
// will happen.
defer func() {
    // Close the pipe
    w.Close()
    // Run the pager
    if err := pager.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    // restore stdout
    os.Stdout = stdout
}()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a somewhat naive **cat** example that uses `$PAGER` when set.

```
package main

import (
        "io"
        "log"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {
        var out io.WriteCloser
        var cmd *exec.Cmd

        if len(os.Args) != 2 {
                log.Fatal("Wrong number of args: gcat <file>")
        }
        fileName := os.Args[1]
        file, err := os.Open(fileName)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error opening file: ", err)
        }

        pager := os.Getenv("PAGER")

        if pager != "" {
                cmd = exec.Command(pager)

                var err error
                out, err = cmd.StdinPipe()
                if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }

                cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

                if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal("Unable to start $PAGER: ", err)
                }

        } else {
                out = os.Stdout
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        file.Close()
        out.Close()

        if cmd != nil {
                if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal("Error waiting for cmd: ", err)
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: ah, it was   `out.Close()` that I was missing. That allows you to use Less navigation without it messing up

Answer (score 2):

This version creates an `io.Writer` called `pager` for all the output that you want paged (you can assign it to `os.Stdout` if you like) and correctly closes that and waits for the `$PAGER` when `main()` returns.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

var pager io.WriteCloser

func main() {
    var cmd *exec.Cmd
    cmd, pager = runPager()
    defer func() {
        pager.Close()
        cmd.Wait()
    }()
    fmt.Fprintln(pager, "Hello, 世界")
}

func runPager() (*exec.Cmd, io.WriteCloser) {
    pager := os.Getenv("PAGER")
    if pager == "" {
        pager = "more"
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(pager)
    out, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return cmd, out
}
```